# Symfony2 - Convert entity proxy to entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to know if it is possible to convert an entity proxy object to an entity object.

I am getting a UserProxy entity instead of a User entity, and when i am doing reflection on this object to get its properties i don't get User properties. How can i get User properties from a User Proxy object ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the real name of proxy class with this methode :

```
$entityName = $em->getClassMetadata($myProxyEntity)->rootEntityName;
```

Once you have your real entity Name, you can create a reflection class